# Getting "cannot create temp directory" error trying to generate jmeter report

Tags: jmeter, reporting

Trying to follow the steps I'm finding on multiple pages [example] (https://helpyoutotest.wordpress.com/2018/03/24/jmeter-how-to-generate-the-dashboard-report-for-your-test/) and I get the .csv output file to generate correctl y, however when i try to run the command line code

```
    jmeter -g "C:\Results\sample7.csv" -o "C:\sample"
```

I get the error text:

```
    2019-01-11 14:23:37,935 main ERROR Null object returned for File in 
    Appenders.
    2019-01-11 14:23:37,947 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "jmeter- 
    log" for logger config "root"
    An error occurred: Cannot create temporary directory "temp".
    errorlevel=1
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir` to be sure to set a temp dir where you have creation / write permissions.
See https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html at 14.2.2 General settings

Comment: So I set the  config parameter as jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir=C:\Users\MyUserName>\Jmeter_Temp, now I'm getting the error:                                                                                                   
    2019-01-14 08:10:09,843 main ERROR Null object returned for File in Appenders.
    2019-01-14 08:10:09,843 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "jmeter-log" for logger config "root"
    An error occurred: Cannot create temporary directory 
"C:Users<MyUserName>Jmeter_Temp".
errorlevel=1

Comment: If you set the path in Windows style, double it (C:\\Users\\...). otherwise set path in Linux style (C:/Users/...)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like user running JMeter does not have the rights to create "temp" folder in the folder where you're running jmeter.

You can modify the output folder by setting in user.properties:

> [jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)=Full Path to a folder where you user has the right to write.

The error message will be improved in next version 5.1 of JMeter with this [commit](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/commit/43d6606890f2151bf4d59a2cdde29ac57b285794).

If you want to learn more about Load Testing and JMeter, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) can help you.